# Tensorflow custom learning rate scheduler gives unexpected EagerTensor type error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, transformer-model

Below is my custom LR Scheduler that subclasses tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule, got error `TypeError: Cannot convert -0.5 to EagerTensor of dtype int64`. Really baffled as to why Eagertensor is relevant to a simple inverse square calculation for the return call of this custom class..

```
class lr_schedule(tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, dim_embed, warmup_steps):
        self.dim_embed = dim_embed
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
    def __call__(self, step):
        return (self.dim_embed ** -0.5) * min((step ** -0.5), step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5))
```

Not specifically relevant to this error, but this is a custom LR Scheduler that replicates warmup scheduler that is used at 'Attention is All You Need' paper..

Comment: have u tried cast to float32? i.e. `tf.cast(self.dim_embed, dtype=tf.float32) ** ...`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I hadn't though of it. When I tried it, it introduced this error though: InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a int64 tensor but is a half tensor [Op:Mul]

Comment: Can u share a reproducible code?

Comment: Edited the question to add a brief reproducible code with mock x_train from a random normal distribution

Comment: This is straightforward. As I mentioned, cast to tf.float32. You need to do that for self.dim_embed and step variable.

Comment: Thanks, I initially casted not during variable declaration but inside the operation, that is why it was not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across this just yesterday.  It's a type coercion issue since the value of `step` being passed into `__call__` is int64, so the math is converting everything to int64.

For your specific case, this should probably fix it:

```py
class lr_schedule(tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, dim_embed, warmup_steps):
        self.dim_embed = tensorflow.cast(dim_embed, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
        self.warmup_steps = tensorflow.cast(warmup_steps, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
    def __call__(self, step):
        step = tensorflow.cast(step, dtype=tensorflow.float32)
        return (self.dim_embed ** -0.5) * min((step ** -0.5), step * (self.warmup_steps ** -1.5))
```

Comment: Thanks to both, casting the variables work.

Comment: As a small side note, I also changed min() to tf.math.minimum() as otherwise it throws an incompatible operator error in graph mode